# Making a link perform jquery with Java in JSP

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp

Making a system with my group in school and got a problem figuring out how to do this...

I have a table, I got JSP to fill out with some data using a for-loop.

Each of the data in the table-cells represent an object using the power of JPA. They, of course, have an `id` of their own.

In our java code, we want to be able to finish off a Task using a method we called `setDone(true)`.

How are can this be done visually on the JSP page? I was guessing Jquery/ajax was a way to do it.

I hope this makes sense. Here you can see the tick/untick buttons.
[image]

**EDIT:**

This is how my HTML/JSP code looks like:

">
                            ">


                        
                        
                            ">
                        
                        
                            ">

And this is the jquery:

```
$(function() {
            $('#done').click(function() {
                $.post("servletUri", {id: idParam, done: doneParam}, function() {
                     $("doneImage-id").attr("src", correction-done.png);
                });
            });
        });
```

But i'm still a rookie to jquery, so I have no idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, jquery is a good option. Here are a few basic steps:

- `<img id="doneImage-${row.id}" onclick="setDone('${row.id}', ${!row.done})" />` in the foreach loop.
- the javascript function `setDone` should invoke a servlet via ajax

  ```
  $.post("servletUri", {id: idParam, done: doneParam}, function() { 
       $("doneImage-id").attr("src", ...); // set here the new image
  };
  ```

This will result in each row invoking the setDone function with a different id parameter, so that it knows what row you've clicked.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but you are using EL like `${row.id}` and that's not how I'm writing the JSP. I have made an edit.

Comment: @KristianB it's almost the same without EL, just more verbose. Output the id there with <%= %> then. But have in mind that EL is the preferred way.

Comment: Ahh, I see. But i'm still in doubt of how to trigger the `setDone()` call to the Java-code, behind. I figure it's done with something like `$('.Correction').click(function() { //Call setDone here!! });`

Comment: @KristianB you can't invoke a method in the java code. You can call a servlet, get the input parameters and perform the logic. In my example `servletUri` is the uri to which the processing servlet is mapped.

Comment: So I _have_ to use a servlet - ok! I'll look in to that. One last thing; if I make a servlet called `actions` I should replaced that with "servletUri"? Is it that simple. I see the params also look like JSON, is that correct?

Comment: you should relace servletUri with whatever `url-mapping` you specify for your servlet. And parameters can be obtained via request.getParameter(..)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the call using jQuery but you'll need something to "answer" that call and actually update the database using JPA. Usually you'll use some type of MVC framework like Spring MVC or Struts, but you can use a plain servlet as well.

To summarize:

1. Add a jQuery click handler to the check image that makes a request to the servlet (with the id or index of the task).
2. Load the JPA object in the servlet or controller and call `setDone` and update.
3. Modify the check image using jQuery appropriately.